# Concrete Floor for 400 Gallon Water Tank

Tags: concrete, floor, cement

I am planning to build a concrete slab on a soil surface to hold a 400 gallon water tank (Shown Below). I want to make it 7' x 7'. It should hold about 3,500 lbs.

Would I need to put in rebar? I've done much smaller slabs with 80 lbs bags of Quikrete Concrete ready mix. How many bags would I need?

[image: Water Tank]

Comment: You're asking for how many bags to use, but you don't tell us how thick you want the pad.  Is the thickness a part of the question?

Comment: Would be helpful if you can mention the layers and thickness too.

Answer (score 1):

### My typical answer to these questions is talk to a Licensed Engineer because there are a lot of considerations that are needed. I firmly stand behind that.

On this project make sure you're using the correct information.

Water ~3,300 pounds

Tank ~ 180 pounds,

Concrete (4in thick without reinforcement) ~2,400 pounds

Piping ? other accessories?

Thats only part of the weight that the ground below your tank will support; how sure are you that the ground will hold that? Typically those tanks don't overflow at their rated capacity, they have 5-15% excess capacity, this needs to be designed to passively let the excess overflow or designed for the tank to be filled the overflow level.

Answer (score 0):

Each bag is .6 cu ft. You have 49 square feet divide by 3 for a 4” slab by 2 for a 6” slab. 49 divided by 3 is 16 cubic feet so it will take just over 27 bags.
Expect to use a bit more as you always use more than expected, I would use a wire mesh reinforcement on a hand pour of this size.